# Group dictionaries in Dictionary.app

Tags: dictionary

I've installed extra dictionaries in Dictionary.app. It's over 9Gb. I'd like to group them by language as is shown in the image below. I've tried to rename their labels in the app, tried editing the Bundle name in Info.plist, but it's not working (dictionaries have same name but not group). Does someone have a solution?

[image: Grouped dictionaries].

Comment: I already reorder them. Now i am looking for file where Dictionary.app store chosen glossaries, then with scripts i can easily change demanded dictionaries. Are you know where this information keeps?

Comment: The dictionaries are in Library/Dictionaries

Comment: I know it. I am looking where information kept about selected dictionaries (in preferences Dictionary.app).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe you can't group dictionaries. However, you can re-order them at will by drag-and-dropping them in Dictionary.app's preferences.